Paginacion de angular no funciona
estoy teniendo problemas con la paginacion de mi pagina, esta echa con angular material, pero deberia mostrarme solo 10 usuarios a la vez,  de echo, me toma la lista completa de los usuarios y los muestra en la pagina  , he intentado de todo, pero no me ha resultado nada.
este es mi archivo.ts:
 export class UserListComponent implements OnInit , AfterViewInit {
      //saveAction: any;
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'nombre', 'username', 'email', 'estado', 'fecha', 'acciones'];
      dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator!: MatPaginator;
      entity: string;
      title: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadUsers();
      }
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
      loadUsers() {
        this.userService.getAll().subscribe({
          next: (response) => {
            const transformedData = response.map(org => ({
              id: org.id,
              nombre: org.name,
              fecha: org.creationDate,
              email: org.email,
              username: org.username,
              estado: this.enumeratorService.getStatusNameFromValue(org.status)
            }));
    
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(transformedData);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; 
          },

y este es mi html:
  <mat-paginator 
        *ngIf="dataSource && dataSource.data?.length" 
        [length]="dataSource.data.length" 
        [pageSize]="10" 
        [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"showFirstLastButtons>      
  </mat-paginator> 

Si me ayudan les estare muy agradecida
de echo he tratado algunas de las respuestas de esta pagina y tampoco

¿Cuál es la versión de angular que estás utilizando?

Hola que tal !
No te recomiendo inicializar tus variables del datasource en el mismo subscribe, ya que esta puede tardar, y puede ocurrir errores inesperados, te recomiendo ponerlo en el mismo oninit o fuera del subscribe

Hola, estoy usando angular 17

Lo que podrías hacer es obtener una referencia al componente MatPaginator usando su referencia local userPaginator en el componente
@ViewChild('userPaginator', { read: MatPaginator }) userPaginator!: MatPaginator;

Modificando la llamada y dejándolo afuera del subscribe
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(transformedData);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.userPaginator; 

Y definir  el HTML de paginación de esta forma:
<mat-paginator 
            #userPaginator 
            [pageSize]="10" 
            [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" showFirstLastButtons>
</mat-paginator>

